# The JIT Script option is not available under Tools=>Option=>Debugger=>JIT

Tags: visual-studio-2017, jit

Under JIT I have Manage and Native

I doesn't find Script Option

I installed :

Visual Studio Community 15.8.9

Visual Studio Professional 15.8.9

Same problem, what I must do?

Answer (score 1):

In order to add the script option you have to modify the Visual Studio Installation, adding the "**ASP.NET and Web development**" option.